# AG Grid cell validations are not updating when rows are updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, react-state

Use Case: I'm using AG Grid to render tables. I have to disable 'Save' button when there is no data in 2 cells(called conditions, terms) in a particular row.

Issue: I've created my own Select component for the column 'condition'. While creating the column definitions, I'm calling CONDITION(myValidationFunction). This function checks all the rows of data, sees if the required cell data is present, and enables/disables accordingly. This works fine until the user explicitly adds more rows. When the user adds more rows, the function 'myValidationFunction' isn't "aware" of the newly added rows.

Code:

Creating column definitions:

```
setColumnDefs([
        SAMPLE_COLUMN_1,
        CONDITION(setPublishButtonState),
        SAMPLE_COLUMN_2,
        SAMPLE_COLUMN_3,
        ...
      ]);
```

CONDITION column definition:

```
export const CONDITION = (setPublishButtonState, autoSizeConditionColumn) => ({
  field: 'condition',
  cellRenderer: Select,
  cellRendererParams: params => ({
    options: CONDITION_OPTIONS,
    mode: 'multiple',

    onChange: values => {
      params.data.condition = values;
      setPublishButtonState(values);
    },
  }),
});
```

myValidationFunction (alias setPublishButtonState):

```
    const MyComponent = (props) => {
        const { rows } = props;
        console.log(rows) // -> gives me the updated rows



        const setPublishButtonState = conditionValues => {

            console.log({ rows }); // gives me the 'old' rows everytime
            validateConditions({ conditionValues, setIsPublishDisabled, rows });
          };

}
```

What I've tried: When rows are updated, inside useEffect, I'm updating the column definition

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFirstRender) {
      const updatedColumnDefs = _map(columnDefs, col => {
        
        if (col.field === CONDITION.field) {
          console.log(rows);
          return CONDITION(setPublishButtonState);
        }
      });
      return updatedColumnDefs;
    }
  }, [rows]);
```

This gives me the following error: 'destroy is not a function at commitHookEffectList'

I want to know why the 'rows' are not getting updated in `setPublishButtonState` function.  Please suggest any possible alternative solutions.